# How can I get rid of "result", "insertedCount", and "insertedIds" from MongoDB callback and node and get only an array of database objects?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I just updated Node after not doing so for a while and had to reinstall MongoDB and other modules.  Where I previously would only get an array of database objects when using the find() function, I'm now getting a JSON object that includes "results", "ops", "insertedCount", and "insertedIds".  I can't remember what I might have done when I initially set it up or maybe this is just an annoying change with Mongo, but I'd like to return to only getting an array of database objects so that I don't have to test my entire server.  I've tried several npm parse modules with no success.

Here's an example:

```
{ result: { ok: 1, n: 1 },
  ops:
   [ { user: '595ee2fec2924e5435dfdd2d'},
       _id: 595f0fe55e84fa2468b17ce8 } ],
  insertedCount: 1,
  insertedIds: [ 595f0fe55e84fa2468b17ce8 ] }
```

Whereas previously, it would have only returned:

```
[ { user: '595ee2fec2924e5435dfdd2d'},
       _id: 595f0fe55e84fa2468b17ce8 } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the ops array.

```
result.ops;
```

You may also need to make sure to follow your call stack correctly as those objects are only returned on an insert.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the resulting object and strip it down to just the array by accessing the `ops` attribute.

```
runMyQuery().then(function(res) {
    return res.ops;
});
```

The previous example makes a lot of assumptions, so don't expect a copy-paste solution.

Answer (score 0):

The most correct solution would be to continue running your project with the exact versions of everything your `package.json` depends on.

That said, I'm assuming you're encountering this issue is because you're running Node locally on your system and needed to upgrade it for another project or security fix. If this is the case, you may want to consider using a Node version management tool like [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) or [nodenv](https://github.com/nodenv/nodenv). These allow you to have multiple versions of Node installed and associate them with individual projects so you don't run into compatibility issues.

For an even more powerful variation of this, you might want to virtualize your entire development environment using a virtual machine such as VirtualBox or a container system like Docker. Both let you create files that define how you'd like to provision your VMs or containers (what OS, what versions of software are installed, etc.). They're the most robust way of ensuring that when you come back to a project months, or even years later, it will still run exactly the way you left it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you inadvertently upgraded from MongoDB 3.X drivers to MongoDB 4.X drivers.  The insert operations now return a much more developer friendly "InsertManyResult" object.  Unfortunately, as far as I can see, this change did not make the [documentation on breaking changes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0-compatibility/#4.0-feature-compatibility).